# Code to make elements fit within their container while keeping their aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, layout

This function receives the id of an element (frame) and calculates the correct height and width so it fits inside its parent element, while keeping its aspect ratio. Before I had a way to calculate the frame ratio dynamically, but I decided it was easier to simply hard code it, it calculates it through naturalHeight and naturalWidth if it's an image, and use 0.5625 for the rest which are iframes, and that ratio makes sense for all of those. It works, tried it in different sizing scenarios, what I'm not 100% sure is if the math involved to calculate the correct width and height in all cases is correct.

In all cases the element should fill as much as possible.

```
function fix_frame(frame_id)
{
    var id = `#${frame_id}`

    var frame = $(id)

    if(frame_id === "media_image_frame")
    {
        var frame_ratio = frame[0].naturalHeight / frame[0].naturalWidth
    }

    else
    {
        var frame_ratio = 0.5625
    }

    var parent = frame.parent()
    var parent_width = parent.width()
    var parent_height = parent.height()
    var parent_ratio = parent_height / parent_width

    var frame_width = frame.width()
    var frame_height = frame.height()

    if(parent_ratio === frame_ratio)
    {
        frame.width(parent_width)
        frame.height(parent_height)
    }

    else if(parent_ratio < frame_ratio)
    {
        frame.width(parent_height / frame_ratio)
        frame.height(parent_height)
    }

    else if(parent_ratio > frame_ratio)
    {
        frame.width(parent_width)
        frame.height(parent_width * frame_ratio)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you posted your code it would help if you told us what you want help with?

This is possible to do using CSS. I've seen multiple solitions, here is the first one I found on Google: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Comment: Basically I want to check if my algorithm is fine. It's possible to do it with CSS using object-fit: contain, I think. The problem with this is that it causes some problems when I used it, so I'm making somewhat my own implementation of it, at least temporarily.

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted? It does not use `object-fit` most solutions rely on setting a margin or padding as a percentage. For example setting `bottom-margin: 100%` will set the bottom margin to 100% of the *`width`*

Comment: I noticed that, but it looks pretty hacky. I try to avoid hacky stuff cause it will probably break later on.

Answer (score 1):

### Style

Some style points...

#### JavaScript style conventions.

- Block delimiters on the same line  eg `if (foo) {` and `} else {`
- `camelCase` for variables not `snake_case`
- Add spaces between `if` and `(` eg `if (` not `if(` same for `for`, `else`, `while`, `do`, `switch`, `return`, etc should all have a white space separating them.
- Hoist `var` declarations to the top of the function

#### Code quality styles

- Use `;` at the end of every line, the exception is if you can list every instance where not including it will cause problems. Most that can do this will end up using `;`
- Use `const` for variables that do not change
- Don't add single use variables unless it improves readability. eg You have something like var `id = "foo"` then `var frame = $(id)`. Would be better as `const frame = $("foo");`
- Don't add unneeded code. You have similar to `if (a === b) { } else if (a < b) {  } else if (a > b) { }` the last if statement is redundant as the execution will only get to that point if a > b
- Don't add variable you don't use. EG you declare `frame_width` and `frame_height` but don't use them.
- Learn to use [ternaries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) as they help reduce the overall source code size and let you use `const` in rather than `var` or `let` when setting values depending on statements.

Aim to reduce the over all code size as it will reduce the chance of bugs and increase the readability of the whole project source.

#### Rewrites

Rewriting you code to have identical functionality.

```
function fixFrame(frameId) {
    const frame = $(`#${frameId}`);
    const frameRatio = frameId === "media_image_frame" ? frame[0].naturalHeight / frame[0].naturalWidth : 0.5625;
    const parent = frame.parent()
    const parentHeight = parent.height();
    const parentWidth = parent.width();
    const parentRatio = parentHeight / parentWidth;
    frame.width(parentRatio < frameRatio ? parentHeight / frameRatio : parentWidth);
    frame.height(parentRatio > frameRatio ? parentWidth * frameRatio : parentHeight);
}
```

Or I would write it using the function context to reduce source code complexity via implied aberrations

```
function fixFrame(id) {
    const frame = $(`#${id}`);
    const fRatio = id === "media_image_frame" ? 
        frame[0].naturalHeight / frame[0].naturalWidth : 
        0.5625;
    const parent = frame.parent()
    const pH = parent.height(), pW = parent.width(), pRatio = pH / pW;
    frame.width(pRatio < fRatio ? pH / fRatio : pW);
    frame.height(pRatio > fRatio ? pW * fRatio : pH);
}
```

Using abbreviations as the context of the function provides the information to know what `pH`, `pW` and `pRatio` and `fRatio` mean.

The declaration of `fRatio` is too long so I made it multi line. Note I had the `?` and `:` at the line ends.

Comment: Cool. I don't personally agree with some of the conventions you mention, but it's nice to see other's perspective. Also you reduced it quite a bit. Thanks